# Make edges point to repelled labels in ggraph

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel, ggraph

I am creating a graph using the ggraph R package. I want to label all the nodes using `geom_node_label()`, but this often create overlaps. One way to fix is this is to use the `repel=TRUE` argument. Unfortunately I cant seem to figure out how to also make the edges point to where the labels have been moved.

One possible way around this would perhaps to make the layout with the repelling before making the graph, but I have not found a way to that either.

```
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)

# Create example graph
my_graph <- make_graph('Meredith')
V(my_graph)$Label <- 1:70


set.seed(2222) # reproducible layout
ggraph(my_graph) +
    geom_edge_link() +
    geom_node_label(aes(label = Label), repel=FALSE) +
    theme_graph()

# Graph with repel = TRUE
set.seed(2222)
ggraph(my_graph) +
    geom_edge_link() +
    geom_node_label(aes(label = Label), repel=TRUE) +
    theme_graph()
```

Here are the plots from of the above code:

- Plot 1:

[image]

- Plot 2:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that workaround can be done because the repelling bit is done at draw-time of the plot, such that it is appropriate for the plot device dimensions. This makes it near-impossible to know the positions of the labels a priori. I'm not that familiar with ggraph and would love to see someone demonstrating that I'm wrong though.